# passing data from node js to react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to pass data from node to react but getting data in text form like `res.text()` perfectly but unable to get data in object form.
Have tried to render with map as well but not working.

REACT JS

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
export default class List extends Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state={apiResponse:[]};
    
  }
callAPI()
  {
    fetch("http://localhost:9000/testAPI")
    .then( (res) => res.json())   
    .then( (json) => {this.setState({apiResponse: json});});
  }

  componentWillMount()
  {
    this.callAPI();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.apiResponse}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

NODE JS

```
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("to-do");
    // var query = { address: "Park Lane 38" };
    dbo
      .collection("to-do")
      .find({})
      .toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        // res.send((result))
        db.close();
      });
  });
  // console.log();
});
```

Comment: Almost there: `res.json(result)`

Comment: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, task, user, dueDate, startDate, complete}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: getting this error.

Comment: Ah, I don't know, this is the next problem. The current problem was "How to send data from Node to React", and this is how. Now, if you have another problem with React, you should open another question

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not sending response in NodeJS Get Request

```
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("to-do");
  // var query = { address: "Park Lane 38" };
  dbo
   .collection("to-do")
   .find({})
   .toArray(function (err, result) {
     if (err) throw err;
     res.send((result))
     db.close();
   });
});

});
```

And then at React Side its a good practice to fetch API results in componentDidMount function instead of componentWillMount.
And if API Response is array/object type then if you only want to display the results in the React, use JSON.stringify(object) like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
export default class List extends Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state={apiResponse:[]};
    
  }
callAPI()
  {
    fetch("http://localhost:9000/testAPI")
    .then( (res) => res.json())   
    .then( (json) => {this.setState({apiResponse: json});});
  }

  componentWillMount()
  {
    this.callAPI();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
    <h1>{JSON.stringify(this.state.apiResponse)}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```